# How to convert a list of elements to n*n space seperated arrangement where n is number of elements in the list

Tags: python-3.x, list

this is my list :
`N= 9`
`Mylist=[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`

For this input
Output should be :

```
9 8 7
6 5 4
3 2 1
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I believe that in the end your question was fine and I'm glad that we were able to help. Next time, it may be useful to share what you have tried and what errors you're running into so that people responding to questions have a better sense of how best to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're wondering how to turn a list into a numpy array of a particular shape. [Documentation is here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape).

```
import numpy as np
my_list=[3,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
# Dropping the first item of your list as it isn't used in your output
array = np.array(my_list[1:]).reshape((3,3))
print(array)
```

Output

```
[[9 8 7]
 [6 5 4]
 [3 2 1]]
```

Comment: I agree with your answer but it is based on several assumptions not present in the original question to include use of numpy, and the fact that the output could be in the form of an array.